# Codeigniter: button which contains data doesn't seem to pass a specific data

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working with a modal+ajax+mvc CRUD and create works fine, but fetching a specific data (data-emiD="'+data[i].m_ID+'") is not working unlike the others that is passed through the button. Why is that? 'm_ID' is AI and INT in my database. I want to DISPLAY m_ID in my edit modal but it's not working.

tried editing the naming convention on the button in each data, but still only the m_ID is not working.

here's my ajax that fetch all data from the database and display in my view

```
function show_manager(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'admin/managers',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_ID+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_username+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_fname+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_status+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_lastlogintime+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_lastloginIP+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].m_loginsystem+'</td>'+
                            '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                       <!----here is the btn that does not pass m_ID--->'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm manager_edit" data-emiD="'+data[i].m_ID+'" data-m_username="'+data[i].m_username+'" data-m_email="'+data[i].m_email+'" data-m_fname="'+data[i].m_fname+'" data-m_status="'+data[i].m_status+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm manager_delete" data-dmiD="'+data[i].m_ID+'">Delete</a>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#show_data').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
```

here is where I want to display the m_ID value in my edit modal which is to verify that I'm fetching it from the datatable/database

```
$('#show_data').on('click','.manager_edit',function(){
        var emid      = $(this).data('emiD');
        var estatus   = $(this).data('m_status');
        var epassword = $(this).data('m_password');
        var efullname = $(this).data('m_fname');
        var eemail    = $(this).data('m_email');
        var eusername = $(this).data('m_username');

        $('#Modal_Edit').modal('show');
        $('[name="emid"]').val(emid);
        $('[name="eusername"]').val(eusername);
        $('[name="estatus"]').val(estatus);
        $('[name="efullname"]').val(efullname);
        $('[name="epassword"]').val(epassword);
        $('[name="eemail"]').val(eemail);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this has been answered by me...It gave me a headache only to realize '"data-emiD"=value' doesn't accept any capital letters. Not quite sure why but it solves my problem by changing it to data-emid="'+data[i].m_ID+'"

Comment: If m_ID is an integer it will only accept numbers. I've never come across Capital Numbers! If you know it should be an integer you can type cast it to be one. PHP will happily use '1' (a string) or 1 (an integer) in most cases it will auto type cast depending upon the context which can be a trap at times. There's more to it but that's for another day.